# Can't get the dom node value extracted

Tags: php, html, dom, screen-scraping

I have a code that links to another site, grabs that data, and returns the string to a variable..  i'm wondering why this isn't working however?

```
<?php


$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT . "http://www.sc2brasd.net";
$doc  = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);


$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');

for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++)
  {
  echo trim($elements->item($i)->nodeValue);
  }

?>
```

there are seven "h1" tags that i would like to grab but they won't return to echo out?  an example of the string would be "Here is the test string i am trying to pull out"

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because the path dont exists. It points to a file on your server.

```
$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT . "http://www.sc2brasd.net";
```

I'n not sure if loadHTMLFile() can handle URLs at all. You may need to get the document with file() and load it with DOMDocument::loadHTML.

Comment: It doenst matter if that url is correct or not. Its still an URL. It produce something like `/etc/http://www.google.com`, and i cant believe that is what you try to parse.